# Starting role from "tasks/alternate.yml" instead of "tasks/main.yml"

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have a large playbook that uses multiple roles to setup new servers.  I'd like to re-use the playbook but for the decommission stage instead of calling into `role_name/tasks/main.yml` and having a lot of `when:` statements, I'd like to tell Ansible to call the role but start in `role_name/tasks/decommission.yml`.

As a first test I setup my `main.yml` file like this:

```
 - name: "Provisioning new server"
   block:
     - name: "Include the provisioning steps."
       include_tasks: provision.yml
   when:
     - not decom

 - name: "DECOM - Unregister from Satellite server"
   block:
     - name: "DECOM - Include the deprovision steps."
       include_tasks: decommission.yml
   when:
     - decom
```

But that's getting really ugly to maintain.  Is this possible or am I overlooking an alternative way to setup the playbook?

Comment: For me, your current `main.yml` looks clean, but why not have one role for setting up new servers and one for decommissioning instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q: ***"Tell Ansible to call the role but start in role_name/tasks/decommission.yml"***

A: Use [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html)

```yaml
    - include_role:
        name: role_name
        tasks_from: decommission.yml
```

,or [import_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html#ansible-builtin-import-role-import-a-role-into-a-play)

```yaml
    - import_role:
        name: role_name
        tasks_from: decommission.yml
```

See [Re-using files and roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#re-using-files-and-roles) on what is the difference between including and importing a role.

Comment: Worked perfectly - thanks, sorry for taking so long to accept this answer!